# Dim rest screen on hover of menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Following is my js fiddle in which i tried to create a light out effect like the following website bankalhabib.com, The issue is that on hover on menu my rest of screen is not getting dim which i actually want and instead only my menu is getting dim.

Kindly let me know ow can i resolve this issue so i can achieve the same effect as above mentioned site?

Thanks,

http://jsfiddle.net/49Qvm/9/

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Num</li>
</ul>

$('li').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

Comment: just a heads up, you can get the "all menu items but the one ur hovering" effect with CSS only => http://jsfiddle.net/49Qvm/24/. i know this doesn't do the "rest of the page fadeout" thing, this is a side note.

Comment: @user I updated with a working example of what you're trying to do

Comment: @Evan http://jsfiddle.net/49Qvm/32/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to create an element for the darken effect on the screen. When you hover over the `ul` element it will toggle the visibility of the darkening element.

You will need to be sure that the `z-index` value for the `ul` element is higher than the element that provides the darkening effect (**Remember this!** When setting `z-index` on an element you will need to be sure to set it's `position` CSS property to `relative`, `fixed`, or `absolute`).

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49Qvm/28/

Comment: WOW, thanks alot i used this update :) http://jsfiddle.net/49Qvm/31/ Thanks to you :)

Comment: Aww yeah! This is perfect, thank you. Using on the nav at www.SkyRooms.IO come and check it out! (I hope this ends up being future-proof lol)

Answer (score 5):

Try this javascript/css that utilizes `z-index` to create a focused effect.

**CSS**

```
.link {
  z-index: 700;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
.dim {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -6;
  display: none;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

body {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var $dim = $('.dim');
$('.link').hover(function(){
  $dim.fadeIn(200);
}, function(){
  $dim.fadeOut(200);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="dim"></div>
<ul>
  <div class="link"><li>Home</li></div>
  <div class="link"><li>Home</li></div>
  <div class="link"><li>Home</li></div>
  <div class="link"><li>Home</li></div>
</ul>

Some text here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49Qvm/33/

Comment: Very good answer, works good. Current accepted answer is just a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this is a scoping issue. Inside the context of the function, "this" refers to the function not the li element. I used to run into a lot of problems related to this. The solution for my cases were to look into using closures to ensure you are adding the class to the correct html element.